# How to blink 3d object continuously in sceneKit in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, 3d, scenekit

How to blink 3d object continuously in sceneKit in swift 3?

Currently, when user press/select 3d object(sphere) then blink one time.

All objects(Sphere) created in 'abc.scn' file.

How to blink object(sphere) every 1 second continuously.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this using `SCNAction`s. You can create a sequence `SCNAction` that looks like this:

```
var fadeOut = SCNAction.fadeOut(duration: 0.1)
var wait = SCNAction.wait(duration: 0.8)
var fadeIn = SCNAction.fadeIn(duration: 0.1)

var blink = SCNAction.sequence([fadeOut, wait, fadeIn])
var continuousBlinking = SCNAction.repeatForever(blink)

yourObject.runAction(continuousBlinking)
```

This should cause the object to continue fading in and out over the course of one second forever.